# Do a sum in View based on criteria

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Model and view something like this:
[Model and View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zb2ZL.jpg)

I want to display the sum/total based on either State or Federal (see the green box in the image).

Here is my view so far.

```
@if (Model.Any())
{
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>
            </th>
            <th>
                STATE
            </th>
            <th>
                FEDERAL
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="180">
                Project
            </th>
            <th width="120">
                Sponsor
            </th>
            <th width="120">
                Sponsor
            </th>
        </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Project)
                </td>

                @if (item.Provider == "State")
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Sponsor)
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Sponsor)
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

How can I display the value (in the green box)? I know that doing a sum in View is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linq with this.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Project)
        </td>

        @if (item.Provider == "State")
        {
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Sponsor)
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        }
        else
        {
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Sponsor)
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
}
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>@Model.Where(x => x.Provider == "State").Sum(x => x.Sponsor)</td>
    <td>@Model.Where(x => x.Provider != "State").Sum(x => x.Sponsor)</td>
</tr>
```